# My FirebaseStorage method isn't Running in Flutter. After the `firebase_storage: ^4.0.0`

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

### My Problem

Can Anyone Help I'm trying to send my images to firebase storage then retrieving the download URL and saving to the firebasefirestore. But my FirebaseStorage method isn't running.

Happening After `firebase_storage: ^4.0.0` **update**

> My `FirebaseStorage().ref().child('path).putFile()` method isn't running

```
FirebaseStorage()
             .ref()
             .child("Accounts Posts/Images/").putFile(//MyFIle);
```

### Here's my Code

```
static final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
static final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

---

```
Future<dynamic> sendData(SearchTileModel st, List<File> data) async {
 bool completed = false;
 CollectionReference _collec = _firestore.collection('Accounts Posts');
 List<String> _imageUrls = [];
 print(data.length);
 data.length > 0
     ? data.asMap().forEach((
         index,
         element,
       ) async {
         print(index);
         print(element);
         String downloadUrl;
///////  HERE this code doesn't get called up  ////////////
         StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseStorage()
             .ref()
             .child("Accounts Posts/Images/${index}")
             .putFile(element)
             .onComplete
             .then((value) {
           downloadUrl = value.ref.getDownloadURL().toString();
           return;
         });
         print(downloadUrl);
         print(snapshot);
         print(snapshot.error);
         if (snapshot.error == null) {
           await snapshot.ref
               .getDownloadURL()
               .then((value) => downloadUrl = value.toString());
           print(downloadUrl);
           _imageUrls.insert(index, downloadUrl);
           if (st.images.length == _imageUrls.length) {
             SearchTileModel newModel = st;
             newModel.images = _imageUrls;
             await _collec
                 .doc('${newModel.placeName} : name')
                .set(
                  st.toJson(),
                  SetOptions(mergeFields: [
                    'images',
                  ]),
                )
                .whenComplete(() {
              return completed = true;
            }).catchError((onError) {
              print('${onError.toString()}');
              completed = false;
            });
          }
        } else {
          completed = false;
          print('Error from image repo ${snapshot.error.toString()}');
          throw ('This file is not an image');
        }
      })
    : print('No Images Selected');
if (data.length == 0) {
  SearchTileModel newModel = st;
  newModel.images = _imageUrls;
  await _collec
      .doc('${newModel.placeName} : name')
      .set(
        st.toJson(),
        SetOptions(mergeFields: [
          'images',
        ]),
      )
      .whenComplete(() {
    return completed = true;
  }).catchError((onError) {
    print('${onError.toString()}');
    completed = false;
  });
}
return completed;
}
```

### Here's Debug Console Output

All the print Statements showing the method is not running.
I also thought that due to `await` it was taking time but no after waiting for 10 mins nothing happened.

```
  I/flutter (14005): true
  I/flutter (14005): redtfgn
  I/flutter (14005): File: 
  '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.medium/files/Pictures/scaled_ec614e8a-0522-4cae-97be- 
  3ed50356de9c3343447263121135351.jpg'
  I/flutter (14005): 1
  I/flutter (14005): running
  I/flutter (14005): 0
  I/flutter (14005): File: 
  '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.medium/files/Pictures/scaled_ec614e8a-0522-4cae-97be- 
  3ed50356de9c3343447263121135351.jpg'
  I/flutter (14005): Till Here the code is Running
```

> Update Got these lines

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(17801): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() 
returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@cdf79f2
E/StorageUtil(17801): error getting token 
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for Task
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(17801): No Network Security Config specified, using 
platform default
W/NetworkRequest(17801): no auth token for request
```

---

### I changed the rule of firebase storage too

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /{allPaths=**} {
     allow read, write ;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using **.ref()** in order to get the reference.
Checking the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file), you can see that the used one is **getReference()**

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
```

Therefore, it might be better to set the storage reference as indicated in the documentation. Also the code for uploading the file would be like this:

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);
```

Comment: Please, do read the code that I have written. It's in flutter, and your answer is in JAVA. And also there is no `getReference()` for  the Flutter's `FirebaseStorage()` .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this ,

```
FirebaseStorage()
             .ref()
             .child("Accounts Posts/Images/").putFile(//MyFIle);
```

Try to put this one,

```
FirebaseStorage()
             .ref()
             .child("Accounts Posts/Images/").putData(//MyFIle);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).